# How do I change my code to be compatible with this unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm working on an exercise on the Exercism website, and I've gotten the program written, but it fails one of the tests that Exercism puts it through. I don't quite know what I need to do to fix it, though. Here's my code:

```
import random

ABILITIES = ['strength', 'dexterity', 'constitution',
             'intelligence', 'wisdom', 'charisma']

class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        for ability in ABILITIES:
            setattr(self, ability, roll_ability())
        self.hitpoints = 10 + modifier(self.constitution)


def modifier(constitution):
    return (constitution - 10) // 2


def roll_ability(dice=4, sides=6):
    rolls = []
    for die in range(dice):
        rolls.append(random.randint(1, sides))
    rolls.remove(min(rolls))
    return sum(rolls)
```

Here's the code from the test file that it fails:

```
def test_random_ability_is_within_range(self):
        score = Character().ability()
        self.assertIs(score >= 3 and score <= 18, True)
```

And here is the failure message:

```
________________________________ DndCharacterTest.test_random_ability_is_within_range _________________________________

self = <dnd_character_test.DndCharacterTest testMethod=test_random_ability_is_within_range>

    def test_random_ability_is_within_range(self):
>       score = Character().ability()
E       AttributeError: 'Character' object has no attribute 'ability'

dnd_character_test.py:58: AttributeError
```

I guess I need an object attribute called "ability?" But what does it do? I'm not a fan of having to write the program so specifically just so it can pass the unittest! I guess I need to read through the unittest before I begin writing the code so I can know what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Your class has no `.ability()` method, no. Do you have *any* specification on what that method is *supposed* to do? We can't tell you, we don't know the context here.

Comment: Okay, the [D&D Character description](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/afd85e3676014af48a12b3ba2de3c899) is basically woefully underspecified. I'm pretty sure though that they expect `Character().ability()` to return a random ability score, so your `roll_ability()` function should be a method on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read the [D&D Character exercise description](https://exercism.io/my/solutions/afd85e3676014af48a12b3ba2de3c899) this is simply *not specified*. You are right to feel uneasy about having to rely on the tests here to provide you with the specifications, this should just have been described more clearly in your assignment.

The test certainly expects there to be a `Character().ability()` method, and it verifies that this method returns an integer in the range 3-18, inclusive. So reading between the lines of what the description tells you how abilities are calculated and what the test is looking for, you just need to move your `roll_ability()` function to your `Character` class and rename it `ability()`:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        for ability in ABILITIES:
            setattr(self, ability, self.ability())
        self.hitpoints = 10 + modifier(self.constitution)

    def ability(self, dice=4, sides=6):
        rolls = []
        for die in range(dice):
            rolls.append(random.randint(1, sides))
        rolls.remove(min(rolls))
        return sum(rolls)
```

Your own implementation already produces numbers between 3 and 18, inclusive (the sum of the 3 highest dice rolls out of 4), so should pass the test without issues. I've confirmed that the above implementation (plus your `modifier()` function) does indeed pass the unit tests given.

From a design perspective, you were right to use a separate function here. `ability()` is not dependent on any `Character` state, and is not a function that a character instance is expected to perform. Rather than make it a method (with a useless `self` argument), you could compromise here and make it a [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod):

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        for ability in ABILITIES:
            setattr(self, ability, self.ability())
        self.hitpoints = 10 + modifier(self.constitution)

    @staticmethod
    def ability(dice=4, sides=6):
        rolls = []
        for die in range(dice):
            rolls.append(random.randint(1, sides))
        rolls.remove(min(rolls))
        return sum(rolls)
```

As for the `ability()` function implementation, you may want to take a look at the [`heapq.nlargest()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) to cleanly and efficiently pick the top 3 out of 4 dice rolls here:

```
from heapq import nlargest

class Character:
    # ...

    @staticmethod
    def ability(dice=4, sides=6):
        rolls = (random.randint(1, sides) for _ in range(dice))
        return sum(nlargest(dice - 1, rolls))
```

I'd just drop the `dice` and `sides` arguments here [on the basis of YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), or *at least* move the magic numbers `4` and `6` into upper-case global names at the top.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually did try what you suggested (rename "roll_ability" to "ability" and move it into the class), but it didn't work. My mistake was not adding the "self" parameter to the method!

Thanks for making that clear, and for making me feel like I'm not so crazy to be confused by Exercism's implementation of their unittests!